# How do I get the file descriptor of a file opened using TextIO.openIn?

Tags: sml, file-descriptor

In Standard ML, I have opened a file using `TextIO.openIn "myfile.txt"`. This returns a value of type `TextIO.instream`. How do I get the POSIX file descriptor of type `Posix.FileSys.file_desc` from this instream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function which does it, returning a `Posix.FileSys.file_desc option`.

```ml
fun instreamToPosixFD (ins: TextIO.instream) : Posix.FileSys.file_desc option =
  let
    val (TextPrimIO.RD reader, _) =
      TextIO.StreamIO.getReader (TextIO.getInstream ins)
  in
    case #ioDesc reader of
      NONE => NONE
    | SOME id => Posix.FileSys.iodToFD id
  end
```

The use of `option` for the output is consistent with the types in the Basis Library. As far as I can tell, if you open a file with `TextIO.openIn` and pass the result to this function, you will get a `SOME` result. My guess is that `NONE` is only possible for a `TextIO.instream` that is not backed by an open file.