# How do I get a TextIO.instream from a POSIX file descriptor?

Tags: sml, file-descriptor

If I have a POSIX file descriptor of type `Posix.FileSys.file_desc`, how to I convert it into a `TextIO.instream`? I want to do the reverse of [How do I get the file descriptor of a file opened using TextIO.openIn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300746/how-do-i-get-the-file-descriptor-of-a-file-opened-using-textio-openin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do the trick. It requires a "name" for the instream, which the [basis library claims](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/posix-io.html#SIG:POSIX_IO.mkBinReader:VAL) is used for error messages shown to the user. So I would recommend using the name or path of the underlying file, if there is one.

```ml
fun fdToInstream (name: string, fd: Posix.FileSys.file_desc) : TextIO.instream =
  let
    val (flags, _) = Posix.IO.getfl fd
    val isNonBlockMode = Posix.IO.O.anySet (Posix.IO.O.nonblock, flags)

    val reader: TextIO.StreamIO.reader =
      Posix.IO.mkTextReader
        { fd = fd
        , name = name
        , initBlkMode = not isNonBlockMode
        }

    val stream_ins: TextIO.StreamIO.instream =
      TextIO.StreamIO.mkInstream (reader, "")
  in
    TextIO.mkInstream stream_ins
  end
```

Comment: Thank you. How do you know all this?

Comment: I'm very familiar with SML (I use it everyday in research), but this sort of function isn't something that I know off the top of my head. It took me 15 minutes or so to look through documentation and chase type definitions to put it together. It's a fun puzzle for me :)

Comment: Perhaps it's a fun puzzle for me because I already know SML so well. But I really wish this sort of stuff was more accessible. The SML Basis Library is sadly a bit of a mess... I had to look at 10 different pages in the library documentation to put this function together. I also had to experiment a bit in the REPL to check that the types were lining up.

Navigating libraries is a strange sort of skill of its own...